# Objective-C++ assigning values to OBj-C properties from C++ object

Tags: c++, objective-c, xcode5, objective-c++

Ok, first, I must admit that this is my first experience with C++. With that cleared, I would like to proceed. The question is as simple as that, but with some (weird) twist. I am trying to wrap a C++ library into Objective-C code. Suppose the C++ class named "my_class" has a has a method "get_string", which returns another class "my_second_class" which has a method named "my_string", which returns an std::string and I want to put it into a property NSString named "MyNSString" for my Obj-C Class "MyClass".

Here's the code. I've skipped the includes/imports and the 'using namespace' parts. They exist.

MyClass.h

```
@interface Torrent : NSObject {
    my_class myCls;

@property NSString *MyNSString;

- (instancetype)initWithHandle:(void*)handle;
- (void)setInfo;

@end
```

MyClass.m

```
@implementation MyClass

@synthesize MyNSString;

- (instancetype)initWithHandle:(void*)handle {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        myCls = static_cast<my_class*>(handle);
        if (! myCls->is_valid()) return nil;
        [self setInfo];
    }
    return self;
}
```

I have not implemented setInfo. That is where the errors start. So, I will go through each of my attempts which are specific to the question.

Attempt #1

```
- (void)setInfo {
    my_second_class mySecCls = myCls->get_string();
    MyNSString = @(mySecCls.my_string().c_str());
}
```

Attempt #2

```
- (void)setInfo {
    MyNSString = @(myCls->get_string().my_string().c_str());
}
```

Attempt #3

```
- (void)setInfo {
    my_second_class mySecCls = myCls->get_string();
    NSString *unusedString = @(mySecCls.my_string().c_str());
}
```

Attempt #1 fails, #2 and #3 succeed.
I also must mention that there are ~75 such values which need to be updated every one second(I use NSTimer in code), so attempt #2 is a hit on performance. #3 is clearly useless, but somehow, it works. I want to know why #1 fails, while #3 and #2 succeed.

I would also appreciate it if somebody could give me the link to some modest(not too big, nor too small) Objective-C++ code.

EDIT:
Attempt #1 causes EXC_BAD_ACCESS code=1

Thanks.

Comment: Please post the code for your C++ classes

Comment: Also, how is attempt #2 less performant than #1 would be ?

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong here, but I'd assumed that more calls = less performance. So, object = anotherObject.getObject; property1 = object.prop1; property2 = object.prop2; is better than property1 = anotherObject.getObject.prop1; property2 = anotherObject.getObject.prop2;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my guess, as we're currently missing some relevant information.
Does your `get_string()` method maybe return a (possibly const) reference to a `my_second_class` instance ?
If that is the case, then the first attempt fails because `mySecCls` is a local object that gets destroyed when the function returns. After that destruction happens, `MyNSString` points to some invalid memory location on the stack. The second attempt works because no such local (i.e. temporary, from the point of view of your class) object gets created, and the pointer passed points to the contents of the more durable `myCls` object.

(I also assume that `my_string()` returns a `const std::string&` and not a `string`, or you'd get the same kind of issue with the resulting temporary variable).

If you want to make something that works like attempt #2, but looks a bit more like attempt #1, you can try:

```
- (void)setInfo {
    const my_second_class& mySecCls = myCls->get_string();
    MyNSString = @(mySecCls.my_string().c_str());
}
```

However, this is pretty much equivalent to attempt #1.

Comment: You are right in both of your assumptions. But, this still doesn't explain Attempt #3, which succeeds. Also, it would be better if you could show an example. As I said, I'm an idiot when it comes to C++. But, I've started reading a book. Hopefully, I'd finish it within a week. Gosh, I gotta learn C++, don't I? Also, if you know some good Objective-C++ project, from which I can find such examples myself, I'd be grateful. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Attempt #3 may very well succeed (i.e. not crash) even though the behavior is undefined, because the compiler optimizes away the local NSString that you create. This is just a guess

Comment: Well, if we ignore Attempt #2, we can deduce that the error is with the MyNSString. If we ignore Attempt #3, we deduce that the problem is with mySecCls. But, in the situation, we have to consider both. I can't decide what the problem is.

Comment: By "working", I meant having the correct behavior, not "not crashing". Attempt #3 may not crash, but it does nothing useful either.

Comment: No, I used breakpoints and the values assigned are correct. Maybe we should discuss this at chat. It's getting a bit too long, and then post the correct answer.